# plot each unique category and save it with specific size

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

NOTE: The past question was deleted and I decided to put the whole problem which I'm trying to solve, as the answers anwered the question I asked but didn't solve the problem.

So, I have this dataframe:

```
> head(dfz)
            X    Y   Question  Category
1        1.00 0.32         Q1       FIN
5        0.27 0.61         Q2       IKA
6        0.13 0.39         Q3       OKS
7        0.25 0.60         Q4       RES
9        0.09 0.57         Q5       RES
12       0.04 0.39         Q6       IKA
```

I need a ggplot for each category (they are 30 unique categories but you can see 4 of them above) with theirs `X` and `Y` values and the `Question` as label.

The ggplot code (simplified):

```
ggplot(FIN, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + 
    geom_point(colour="red",size=3) +
    geom_text_repel(label=df$Question, family="sans", fontface="bold", size=4) +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1), position = "right")
```

Each plot has to be saved in a specific folder. In this folder we will have those 30 plots in different `.png` files (30 `.png` files to be exact). The name of each file has to be its category value (for category `FIN` the file should be  `"C:/ME/Plots/FIN.png"`, for `IKA` should be `"C:/ME/Plots/IKA.png"`, etc.).

The expected output is this:

```
[1] "C:/ME/Plots/FIN.png " # Plot of FIN category
[1] "C:/ME/Plots/PLE.png " # Plot of IKA category
[1] "C:/ME/Plots/OKS.png " # Plot of OKS category
[1] "C:/ME/Plots/INX.png " # Plot of RES category
[1] "C:/ME/Plots/MES.png " # Plot of PLZ category
```

So, I decided to take the next approach:
(1) Create 30 dataframes, (2) create a list of those 30 dataframes, (3) Loop through that dataframe list, (4) plot each loop, (5) save the plot of each loop in the specific folder. However, I'm struggling with calling the "name" of the dataframe each time the loop works (this struggling was solved in the past question, but not the whole problem so we decided to delete it and make a new question)

A simpler approach could be (but I don't have any idea how to implement it):
(1) Tell ggplot() to print one plot per category and (2) save it with `ggsave()` in the specific folder with the name of the category as the name of the `.png` file.

PS: The saving of the plot HAS to be with `ggsave()` as its needed to have a specific size.

Comment: @RLave here is the full problem

Comment: @KonradRudolph here is the full problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `by` to iterate through the unique values of *Category* and save each subset data graph to disk using `ggsave`:

```
by(dfz, dfz$Category, function(sub) {
   g <- ggplot(sub, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + 
           geom_point(colour="red",size=3) +
           geom_text_repel(label=sub$Question, family="sans", fontface="bold", size=4) +
           scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)) + 
           scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1), position = "right")

   fn <- paste0("C:/ME/Plots/", sub$Category[1], ".png")

   ggsave(file=fn, plot=g, device = "png")    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(scales)

# create directory where to save plots
dirpath <- file.path("C:", "ME", "plots")

if (!dir.exists(dirpath)) {
  dir.create(dirpath, showWarnings = F, recursive = T)
}

# define plotting function
fff <- function(d, dirpath) {
  #plot
  p <-
    ggplot(d, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + 
    geom_point(colour="red",size=3) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label=Question), 
                    family="sans",
                    fontface="bold", 
                    size=4) +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1),
                       position = "right") 
  #save
  fn <- paste0(as.character(d$Category[1]), ".png")
  fp <- file.path(dirpath, fn) 
  ggsave(filename = fp, plot = p)
}

# split data to list by Category
dfz_sp <- split(dfz, dfz$Category)

# save the plots
dfz_sp %>%
  walk(fff, dirpath)
```